# POST command to WebCeo API

Tags: api, google-apps-script

Trying to connect to this [WebCEO API](https://online.webceo.com/download/Web%20CEO%20Online%20API.pdf).

```
function getProjects() {
  var payload = {
    "key": "CUSTOMER_KEY",
    "method": "get_projects"
  };

  payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

  var url = "https://online.webceo.com/api/";

  var options = {
    "method": 'POST',
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload": payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Receiving "Request failed for https://online.webceo.com/api/ returned code 404".

Any hint on what else I need to include / change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body must contain the following:

```
json={"key": "YOUR_API_KEY", "method": "get_projects"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `https://online.webceo.com/api/` does return a 404 when you just try to access it. Did you manage to get that page to not return a 404 error from another client?

Doing so will probably tell you what you're missing here.

However, I'd suspect their API might be having issues.

Comment: Haven't accessed it other ways.  Was assuming I either need to build the url out more or add in other authorization fields.

Comment: I see a 404 as well. However, the 404 is for the GET method which browsers invoke. I suggest you try the same request with some other REST Client (my favourite is Postman which is a Chrome plugin)

Answer (score 0):

That's true, you don't make a GET request. You have to send parameters in the body of a POST request. Below is an example in CURL for a situation when you need to get the list of projects:

```
curl -X POST -d 'json={"key": "YOUR_API_KEY", "method": "get_projects" }' https://online.webceo.com/api/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please suggest what the problem is, why does he get a 404?